# Spark: confused about number of executors and what web ui displays

Tags: performance, apache-spark, cpu-cores

I'm beginning with Spark and I'm a little bit confused about the tuning part. My cluster has 3 machines (128G each) and each of them has 2 sockets, 8 cores per socket and 2 threads per core.

First of all, what is the maximum number of executors that I have access to (theoretically, with only 1 core par executor)? Is it 48 (3*8*2) or 96 (3*8*2*2)?

Second, when I try to launch Spark with the following parameters (assuming that the answer to the preceding question was 48):

```
pyspark --master spark://... --num-executors 8 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 38g
```

why does the web ui (port 4040, executors tab) show only 4 executors with the following info:

```
executor id    address    storage memory
driver         {mynode1}     0/384M
0              (mynode2}     0/21.6G
1              (mynode1}     0/21.6G
2              (mynode3}     0/21.6G
```

How should I interpret these numbers? How do they relate to the parameters I specified in the command line? How come I have only 4 executors and not 8? Thanks for help me clarifying this!

EDIT: thanks for the link @user6910411, it helped me but it does not fully answer my question. There is this question about the total number of cores that I have access to (actually I realized that on spark UI url:8080, I see the total number of cores available per worker and this number is 6 cores per worker; I don't understand why this is 6 and not 16 or 32 given the numbers of sockets (8) and cores per socket (2) and threads per core (2) that I have. There is also the question about the memory shown on the executors page that is not the one I specify when I invoke pyspark. Example:

```
 pyspark --master spark://... --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 4g --total-executor-cores 18
```

On the web UI, I see that the PySparkShell is consuming 18 cores and 4G per *node* (I asked for 4G per *executor*) and on the executors page, I see my 18 executors, each having 2G of memory. Other experiments let me think that this number is always the half of the number I request. Maybe it's related to this number of cores per socket or threads per core (2 in each case)?